# flexVolume plugin not working on gke windows node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, smb

I'm trying to run a simple flexvolume plugin driver on windows node to enable connectivity with an external SMB share. I followed the steps listed out here
https://github.com/microsoft/K8s-Storage-Plugins/tree/master/flexvolume/windows

Placed the driver plugin in the mentioned path but the problem is the plugin is not getting picked up by gke. The error details are as below.

```
  Warning  FailedMount  8s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, gke-windows-node-pool-e4e7a7bf-f2pc  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[smb-volume], unattached volumes=[default-token-jf28b smb-volume]: failed to get Plugin from volumeSpec for volume "smb-volume" err=no volume plugin matched
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be great. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What Windows image did you use and what version of GKE? So you extracted file to `C:\usr\libexec\kubernetes\kubelet-plugins\volume\exec\ ` What exactly YAMLs did you deployed from this tutorial?

Comment: Hi @PjoterS. I used the yamls provided in the samples section present in the same repo. <https://github.com/microsoft/K8s-Storage-Plugins/blob/master/flexvolume/windows/sample_yamls/smb.yaml>. GKE version is 1.16.8-gke.15 (1 Linux node + 2 Windows nodes)

Comment: Could you provide Yours steps to reproduce this behaviour? What version of Windows and Linux (Ubuntu, CentOS)?

Comment: @Init_Rebel, please try to deploy SMB flex volume driver to 'c:\etc\kubernetes\flexvolume' location, GKE's Windows node is using a non-standard location for "volume-plugin-dir" (is specified as an arg to kubelet, what you can verify in instance metadata).

Comment: if you still have this issue, I would rather recommend you to file an issue at GCP support, using their [public issue tracker for GKE](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=1162666)

Answer (score 2):

Just faced with a similar issue on a kubeadm on prem configuration, have used [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find the proper location the kubelet.exe process looks for volume plugins.

As result my actual windows node SMB preparation:

```
curl -L https://github.com/microsoft/K8s-Storage-Plugins/releases/download/V0.0.3/flexvolume-windows.zip -o flexvolume-windows.zip
Expand-Archive flexvolume-windows.zip C:\var\lib\kubelet\usr\libexec\kubernetes\kubelet-plugins\volume\exec\
```